# EF Core tree structure explicit loading: suppress duplicating child nodes

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an object structure like

```
RootNode
 int id
 HashSet<Node> Nodes
 
Node
 int RootId
 RootNode Root
 int ParentId
 Node Parent
 HashSet<Node> Nodes
```

My db context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RootNode>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasMany(t => t.Nodes)
            .WithOne(n => n.RootNode)
            .HasForeignKey(n => n.RootId);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Node>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(s => s.RootNode)
           .WithMany(t => t.Nodes)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.RootId);

    entity.HasOne(s => s.Parent)
           .WithMany(ps => ps.Nodes)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentId)
           .IsRequired(false);
});
```

I try to explicitly load the RootNode object with all it's child nodes. I use queue to avoid recursion and in my test entity Root object has one child node and this node also have one nested node

```
var root = _dbContext.Roots.First(x => x.Id == myRootId);

root.Children = _dbContext.Nodes.Where(x => x.RootId == myRootId && x.Parent == null)
                                .ToHashSet();

var queue = new Queue<Node>();

foreach (var node in root.Nodes)
{
    queue.Enqueue(node);
}

while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    var node = queue.Dequeue();
// here I have
// > Root
// >    Node1
    node.Nodes = _dbContext.Nodes.Where(x => x.ParentId == node.Id)
                                     .ToHashSet();
// here my Root has 3 nodes instead of 2
    foreach (var subnode in node.Nodes)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(subnode);
    }
}
```

After I load child nodes instead of expected

```
  Root
     Node1
         Node1-1
```

I get

```
  Root
     Node1
         Node1-1
     Node1-1 (copy)
```

How to prevent my child node duplication in a root level when I load subnodes from db context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause: when I saved new entities to the database all subnodes had the `RootId` and `Root` set to the root entity, after changing the type to nullable in the database and setting these values to `null` loading works as expected.